# Doctrine generated SQL statement gives an 1064

Tags: mysql, sql, doctrine-orm

I've a MySQL statement, generated by doctrine which gives an 1064 error. When breaking down the whole SQL I found the error was specific to one table called `group`. To me the query looks fine maybe a more skill ful eye on sql statement sees this?

The error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group ( id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL, creationdate' at line 1
```

The statement:

```
CREATE TABLE group (
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
name VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
creationdate DATETIME NOT NULL, 
deleted TINYINT(1) NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY(id)) 
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GROUP is a [MySQL reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html), rename this table or use backticks (`) -

```
CREATE TABLE `group`(
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
  creationdate DATETIME NOT NULL,
  deleted TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
ENGINE = INNODB;
```

Comment: Ow crap! Hat to see that. Thanks!

Comment: @RoelVeldhuizen: I know that was just a typo, but I thought that it might actually be really nice to have a *hat* to see that. :)

Answer (score 0):

`group` is a reserved word and cannot be used as a table name unless properly quoted.

If your MySQL installation is configured to run in ANSI (standard) mode, it must be quoted using double quotes:

```
CREATE TABLE "group"
```

If your server runs in non-standard mode (which is unfortunately the default), you need

```
CREATE TABLE `group`
```

Answer (score 0):

First guess is because group is a keyword, have you tried

```
CREATE TABLE [group] ( ...
```